# Get datetime in form builder symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.1

How do I get datetime and add in database, I have form type builder like so at (Bundle/Form/ClassType.php)

```
$registered = date('Y-m-d');

$builder->add('registered', TextType::class, array(
    'label' => 'registered',
    'data' => $registered,
));
```

And here is my entity class (Bundle/Entity/Class.php)

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="registered", type="datetime", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
 */
private $registered;
```

The problem is I cannot add this on db, I receive error like

**Error: Call to a member function format() on string**

Any help?

Comment: change date to datetime

Comment: read this - https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use DateType instead of TextType.

```
->add('registered', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'input' => 'string',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'data' => $registered,
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            )
        ))
```

Comment: Hi error Error: Call to a member function format() on string

Comment: Try without 'input' => 'string'

Comment: error Unable to transform value for property path "registered": Expected a \DateTimeInterface.

Comment: Can I use current_timestamp on my form entity so that everytime I made some changes it will override the value of registered? How?

Comment: It's occurs because you pass an string data, you must pass an DateTime object, change $registered = new \DateTime('now');

By other hand if you need change the date everytime you made some changes I recommend you use @HasLifecycleCallbacks, you can find more info here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-haslifecyclecallbacks

Comment: thank you it works now and can be saved now in db, last questions, how do I prevent the user to edit the datetime field? coz I don't like the user to edit the datetime field, the datetitme field only generates date values, e.g 09/12/2016 how can i include the time values? how can I change the format e.g 2016-12-09 08:12:22 instead 09/12/2016 . thank you so much